# different datastore size and data quota

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

why appengine show 800MB in quota Total Stored Data
when
Size of all entities is 116 MBytes
?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indexes created for your data are included in that total. If an entity's property doesn't need an index you should add indexed=False to the property definition.

Answer (score 1):

There's many things that are included in your total stored data.

Including

- Actual Data Store entities
- Indexes (Ones that are automatically created and ones you create)
- Task Queue Stored Task Bytes
- Blobstore Stored Data.

Search for `Stored Data` on the [Quota Page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html) to see more details.